# How to check if a cell is blank while using jxl to read excel files

Tags: java, jxl, jexcelapi

I checked the jxl api to check what the getContent() method returns for an empty cell , but it doesn't explicitly indicate what happens !

ref # : http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6/docs/jxl/Cell.html#getContents%28%29

Can anyone indicate what happens when getContent() is called on a cell which is empty ?

Answer (score 3):

It returns a String of length 0.  This is easily tested on a row like so

```
Cell[] cells = sheet.getRow(10) // selecting row 10 from the current sheet
for (Cell cell : cells) {
   String contents = cell.getContents();
   if (contents == null) {
      System.out.println("Will not print");
   } else if (contents.length() == 0) {
      System.out.println("This will print for a blank cell");
   } else {
      System.out.println("This cell is not empty");
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If above is not working then try below command:

```
string.isEmpty();
```